# usb_control_msg returns -EPIPE

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I am converting WinCE USB Code to Linux, so here is the WinCE code that gets the APP Revision using Control message.

```
        ControlHeader.bmRequestType = USB_REQUEST_DEVICE_TO_HOST | USB_REQUEST_VENDOR | USB_REQUEST_FOR_INTERFACE;
        ControlHeader.bRequest = RADS_GET_APPREVISION;
        ControlHeader.wValue = 0;                               // unused
        ControlHeader.wIndex = 0;                               // unused
        ControlHeader.wLength = sizeof(USHORT);                 // size of output buffer

        dwError = IssueVendorTransfer(pGENDevice->lpUsbFuncs,
                                      pGENDevice->hUsbDevice,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      (USB_IN_TRANSFER|USB_SHORT_TRANSFER_OK),
                                      &ControlHeader,
                                      pusTemp,
                                      0,
                                      &dwBytesTransferred,
                                      0,
                                      &dwUsbError);
```

I converted it as below for Linux:

```
 retval = usb_control_msg(dev->usb_dev,
                                                usb_rcvctrlpipe(dev->usb_dev, 0),
                                                RADS_GET_APPREVISION,
                                                USB_DIR_IN | USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                &appRevision,
                                                sizeof(unsigned short),
                                                USB_CTRL_SET_TIMEOUT);
```

I am getting -EPIPE as retval.  What does the return value -EPIPE signifies

Can you help me in resolving this issue.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: The documentation [states what error codes mean](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.5/source/Documentation/driver-api/usb/error-codes.rst). If you don't know what "stall" means, check the USB specs. A frequent cause of stalls is erroneous data sent to the device.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My error is happening in usb_submit_urb. The pipe type specified in the URB doesn't match the endpoint's actual type. As per my knowledge of USB, each and every USB device has control endpoint, which works in both direction IN and OUT.  To verify control endpoint, I tried USB_REQ_GET_INTERFACE, it returned successfully